# Optimization of 3 variable function without lagrange

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

The temperature in space given by  $T(x,y,z)=200xyz^2$ .

Find the hottest temperature on a unit sphere centered at the origin.(without lagrange multipliers method)

I took $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$
then using $z^2=1-x^2-y^2$, substituted into equation, then found partial derivatives of $T$ wrt $x$ and $y$ and equated to $0$.

What do I do next? Stuck with two equations containing $x$ and $y$.

Comment: use mathjax for using mathematical functions

Comment: What are your two equations? Post them, please.

Comment: Update: I'm finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial derivatives:
$$
\begin{align}
y(1-3x^2-y^2)&=0\\
x(1-x^2-3y^2)&=0
\end{align}
$$
give
$$
\begin{align}
y&=0&\lor&&1-3x^2-y^2&=0\\
x&=0&\lor&&1-x^2-3y^2&=0
\end{align}
$$
that is $(\pm1,0)$, $(0,\pm1)$ and subtraction the second equations yields to $x^2=y^2$ which leads to $x=\pm1/2$.  From here all solution can be found.

Answer (score 0):

First note that you can reduce your consideration to $x,y,z >0$.

Now, a possible non-Lagrange way can be [GM-AM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means):

$$\sqrt[4]{abcd}\leq \frac{a+b+c+d}4$$

For $a,b,c,d\geq 0$ and equality if and only if $a=b=c=d$.

Write

$$1 = x^2+y^2+\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^2}2 \geq 4\sqrt[4]{x^2y^2\frac{z^4}4}$$

Hence,

$$\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\geq \sqrt{xyz^2}$$

or
$$xyz^2 \leq \frac 18$$
with equality at $x^2=y^2=\frac 14=\frac 12 z^2 \Rightarrow z=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ and $x=y=\frac 12$.

I leave the last step up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Using polar coordinates
$$
\cases{
x=r\sin\theta\\
y=r\cos\theta\sin\phi\\
z=r\cos\theta\cos\phi
}
$$

we transform the problem into

$$
\max_{\theta,\phi}200r^4\sin\theta\cos^3\theta\sin\phi\cos^2\phi\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ r^2=1
$$

or

$$
\max_{\theta,\phi}k f(\theta)g(\phi)
$$

here $\theta, \phi$ are independents.